# Clustering using gower distance in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, categorical-data, mixed-type

I have a dataframe which has categorical and numeric variables. I want to cluster this data using gower distance and get cluster values as a vector as in kmeans function. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Use PAM, CLARA etc. that work with arbitrary distances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the vegan package to generate your gower matrix, and then create your clusters using the cluster package.

```
gow.mat <- vegdist(dataframe, method="gower")
```

Then you can feed that matrix into the PAM function. The example below will use the gower distance to generate 5 clusters

```
clusters <- pam(x = gow.mat, k = 5, diss = TRUE)
```

You can then get your cluster information from

```
clusters$clustering
```

Comment: k-means first parameter should be the raw input data, *not* a distance matrix.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, you're absolutely right. I've edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kproto()` function from `clustMixType` if you don't want to insist on using Gower distance. The distance measure in `kproto` is similar to Gower distance except that `kproto` uses Euclidean distance to measure dissimilarity between numerical variables; however, Gower distance normalizes each variable (divides the distance between two observations by the range of that variable). The code is pretty simple.

```
kproto_clustering <- kproto(df, k)   # k is number of cluster
clusters <- kproto_clustering$cluster
```